# share video using UIActivityViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to share video with UIActivityViewController without using any custom UIActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately it's not possible to do this yet.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, you can share videos on facebook using UIActivityViewController. Not sure about other services though.